# Conditional Probabilities Problem (If the selected student did not fail english, what is the probability that he failed math or did not fail science?)

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

The chances of selecting a student at random who failed math, science, and
and english are 0.3125, 0.4375, and 0.375, respectively. The chance that the
selected student failed all these subjects is 0.0625; while the chance that he did not fail any of these subjects is 0.225. If the selected student failed math, then the chance that he did not fail science is 0.56. If the selected student failed english, then the chance that he failed math is 0.3.
$$\begin{gathered}\text{Given}: P(M)=0.3125\quad P(S)=0.4375 \quad P(E)=0.375\\ P(MSE)=0.0625 \quad P(M^cS^cE^c)=0.225\\ P(S^c|M)=0.56\quad P(M|E)=0.3\end{gathered}$$
I have included below the questions and my attempts to answer them.

1). What is the probability of selecting a student who failed english or science?
$$ P(E \cup S)= P(S)+P(E)-P(ES)$$
I used De Morgan's on $P((MSE)^c)$ to find $P(M\cup S\cup E)$ then inclusion-exclusion to find $P(ES)$ and eventually got $P(E\cup S)=0.1625$

2). What is the probability of selecting a student who failed science and math but not english?
$$P(S ME^c)$$
Here, I used definition of set difference then property of probability function to get $P(SME^c)=P(SM)-P(SME)=0.075$
$$$$
3). If the selected student did not fail english, what is the probability that he failed math or did not fail science?
$$ P(M\cup S^c|E^c)$$
For this one, I don't know how to get $P((M\cup S^c)\cap E^c)$. Please let me know how I can start on this and if I made any mistakes above.

Comment: The event that the student did not fail on any of these subjects is not $(MSE)^c$ but is $M^cS^cE^c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to solve these exercises using Venn's diagrams.

After a little brainstorming you get this diagram

[image]

which shows you the answer to any question they can put you. Numbers are expressed in %

---

In the particular case, your answers are the following

> 1). What is the probability of selecting a student who failed english or science?

$$77.5-12.5=65\%$$

> 2). What is the probability of selecting a student who failed science and math but not english?

$$7.5\%$$

> 3). If the selected student did not fail english, what is the probability that he failed math or did not fail science?

$$22.5+12.5+7.5=42.5\%$$

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I just have a question about $P(ME)=0.09375$, when I use the given formula which is $P(ME)=P(M|E)*P(E)$ it gives me $0.1125$ but the correct answer which is $0.09375$ comes when $P(M)$ is multiplied instead of $P(E)$. Did I write the given wrong or misinterpret any of them?

Comment: @tars : you are right. I was in a hurry and I did some errors in calculations. Now all is correct